# Where to find NSOrderedSet (Objective C) source code ? Reading elements from SET in the order of insertion in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, set

Is there any possibility of reading elements from `SET` (in C++ i,e std::set) on the basis of order of insertion of those elements into SET (in C++)? 
I could have used Vector or list for reading in the order of insertion. But I want insertion, searching etc to be done in O(log(n)). Using SET is requirement, I can't change that.

Usage of extra memory for storing element id or insertion sequence number etc will require a lot of memory. Solutions of this kind are not helpful to me

I read some where that in Objective-C, NSOrderedSet give this kind of functionality ( I do not know Objective-C, NSOrderedSet ). Can the similar functionality be achieved in C++?

Edit1: Is `NSOrderedSet` source code available? If available, where Can I find?

Comment: std::set<T> are ordered based in the order function of the value type T... but the order of insertion is lost. You could store a wrapper object instead to keep track of the order of insertion.

Comment: @jsantander: Can you please explain about wrapper object..

Comment: Is Boost an option ? if so see [multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: You write "a lot of memory" what kind of application is it? Can you show some details of the original requirements?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::map` with key your objects and value the order of insertion in the `map` (see example below):

```
std::map<yourObj, std::size_t> M;
...
M.insert(std::make_pair(yourObj, M.size() + 1));
```

This way you retain the insertion, searching etc to be done in `O(log(n))` requirement.

Comment: Doesn't using map increase the memory requirement?